# How to access the meta data of QMediaPlayer?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to access the metadata of the mp3 file and put it in the labels but the program doesn't read it.
I read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediametadata.html.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work properly (besides QFileInfo).

```
path = item->text(); //text is a path from QFileDialog::getOpenFileName
/*QMediaPlayer*/ sound.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
 QFileInfo info(path);

        ui->label_3->setText(sound.metaData("Title").toString());
    if (ui->label_3->text()=="")
        ui->label_3->setText(sound.metaData("AlbumTitle").toString());
    if (ui->label_3->text()=="")
    ui->label_3->setText(info.baseName());

 ui->label_5->setText(sound.metaData("Author").toString());
    if (ui->label_5->text()=="")
        ui->label_5->setText(sound.metaData("AlbumArtist").toString());
    if (ui->label_5->text()=="")
        ui->label_5->setText(sound.metaData("Composer").toString());
```

Library and multimedia are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

It takes time for the media to be loaded after calling [`QMediaPlayer::setMedia`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia), hence requesting the meta data right after the media has been set results in:

```
QVariant(Invalid)
```

## Solution

I would suggest you to wait for the media to be loaded by connecting to the [`QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged) and reading the meta data once the status becomes [`QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#MediaStatus-enum).

**Note:** If you make `sound` a local variable, it would be destroyed when it goes out of scope. Better use `auto *sound = new QMediaPlayer(this);`.

## Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you of how you could change your code in order to implement to proposed solution:

```
connect(sound, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged, [this, sound, info](QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status){
    if (status == QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia) {
        ui->label_3->setText(sound->metaData("Title").toString());
        if (ui->label_3->text()=="")
            ui->label_3->setText(sound->metaData("AlbumTitle").toString());
        if (ui->label_3->text()=="")
            ui->label_3->setText(info.baseName());

        ui->label_5->setText(sound->metaData("Author").toString());
        if (ui->label_5->text()=="")
            ui->label_5->setText(sound->metaData("AlbumArtist").toString());
        if (ui->label_5->text()=="")
            ui->label_5->setText(sound->metaData("Composer").toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for suggests, but I get the message: " 'sound' in capture list does not name a variable.". I store sound as a QMediaPlayer variable in the mainwindow.h file. Should I store it somewhere else to make it work?

Comment: @Nve, Change `[this, sound, info]` to `[this, info]`.

Comment: I have also added & to sound (&sound) and now it's fully working, thanks.