# Read QMediaMetaData without wait after set the media source

Tags: qt, mkv, qmediaplayer, qt6

Qt 6.2.0 / Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to read the title tag from a mkv video file. So at first I'm trying to retrieve all the available tags:

```
QMediaPlayer p;
p.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(dir.absolutePath()));
QMediaMetaData metadata = p.metaData();
QList<QMediaMetaData::Key> keys = metadata.keys();
foreach (QMediaMetaData::Key key, keys)
{
    qDebug() << key;
}
```

The list is empty.
I'm aware the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmediametadata.html) say:

> Not all identifiers are supported on all platforms

But I cannot believe no one metadata is there!
The title tag is surely there because, say, VLC reads it correctly.
Is my approach wrong?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053201/how-to-access-the-meta-data-of-qmediaplayer) it seems `QMediaPlayer` needs some time to extract the tags. Is there a different approach that avoid this waste of time?

The goal is to extract the `title` (or other info) from hundreds of video files so I cannot wait so long for each one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the meta data of QMediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053201/how-to-access-the-meta-data-of-qmediaplayer)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot wait. I need to process tons of video files and extract the tags (basically the title). If there is another way that does not require to wait, please feel free to add an answer. I edit the question.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @scopchanov sorry I don't understand what you are suggesting. I asked for a different approach, showing what I have done until now (the well-known minimal and reproducible example) and you suggest to file a bug report?

Comment: I suggest you to make a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

```
        QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
        player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(folderPath + "/" + fileName));
        QTimer timer;
        timer.setSingleShot(true);
        QEventLoop loop;
        connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged, &loop,&QEventLoop::quit);
        connect( &timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
        timer.start(1000);
        loop.exec();

        if(timer.isActive())
        {
             qDebug()<<player->metaData().keys();
        }
        else
            qDebug("timeout");

        delete player;
```